# Adding PHP to HEREDOC

Tags: php

I am trying to display a little bit of code while the user is on `index.php`.

CODE:

```
<?php 
           $login = "<p>Already registered? <a href='login.php'>Sign in</a></p>";

$footer = <<<FOOTER
    <div id='footer'>
        <?php if($_SESSION['at_index'] = true){ echo $login; } ?>
    </div>
FOOTER;

?>
```

I am receiving this error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"

The session variable `$_SESSION['at_index']` is only true when the user is on index.php.

Question: How can I echo `$login` in my HEREDOC footer?

Comment: you're already in PHP and using tags inside the heredoc. Read the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: then you're assigning `if($_SESSION['at_index'] = true` rather than comparing.

Answer (score 3):

With HEREDOC you can print variables just like in double quoted strings. Unfortunately you cannot use conditional statements there, so you'll need an additional variable:

```
$footerLogin = (true == $_SESSION['at_index']) ? $login : '';
$footer = <<<FOOTER
    <div id='footer'>
        {$footerLogin}
    </div>
FOOTER;
```

Note that you have an "assignment instead of comparison" (= instead of ==) bug in your code. To avoid this kind of bug in the future, always put constant on the left side of the comparison.

Plus, make sure you started the session since it was not shown in your original question, while placing `session_start();` inside all files using sessions if you have not already done so; it is required.